# Why I fail to run a shell script generated by a python script, which gives me "cannot execute binary file" error?

Tags: python, bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux, binaryfiles

I use the powershell to generate a shell script by a python script, as the following.

```
python generate_large_local_array_run.py > large_local_array_run.sh
```

But when I run the shell script using bash in the powershell (or Ubuntu, I got wsl2 installed in my win10), it gives me "cannot execute binary file" error.

```
bash large_local_array_run.sh
large_local_array_run.sh: bash large_local_array_run.sh: cannot execute binary file
```

To solve this problem, I open the shell script `large_local_array_run.sh` in VScode and directly copied the content into a new text file, and save the new text file as `temp.sh`.
This time, I am able to run `temp.sh` in powershell as well as Ubuntu with the command
`bash temp.sh`.
Why is that the case? What's the difference between the original `large_local_array_run.sh` and the new `text.sh`. They are completely the same for raw eye, but do they have some different formats?

Comment: I would do a `cmp large_local_array_run.sh temp.sh` . Does it show some difference?

Comment: It says `differ: byte 1, line 1`, but for me they are both `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: shebang line has windows line feed which, when executed in WSL, tries to run "bash\r" instead of just "bash" ?

Comment: Then it's trivial. You know that at least the first byte is different (`cmp` reports only the first difference), so just open both files with a text editor of your choice and see in which respect the bytes differ. Perhaps one has a BOM and the other one doesn't?

Comment: Run `od -c` or `cat -A` or similar on each file to see the invisible characters.

Comment: Try `python generate_large_local_array_run.py | strings > large_local_array_run.sh` . Does that work?

Comment: @LjmDullaart That works! Thanks! But I don't know why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program

```
python generate_large_local_array_run.py
```

generates a file that is not pure ascii. The problem is probably at the beginning of the file. If possible, you will want to revise the code in `generate_large_local_array_run.py` so that it provides a valid shell script.

```
python generate_large_local_array_run.py | strings > large_local_array_run.sh
```

lets `strings` filter-out the non-printables.

`strings` prints the sequences of printable characters in files. It is a hack that removes the non-printable characters, and those are the characters that `bash` chokes on. It is far from fool-proof. `strings` prints only sequences of at least 4 characters. So,

```
echo something
<binary stuff, non printables>
ls
<binary stuff, non printables>
```

will give you the `echo`, but not the `ls`.

As said: you will need to revise `generate_large_local_array_run.py` to produce a valid script, without the non-printables.